# User change for bitcoin core installation

Tags: bitcoind, linux, installation

I made a mistake and installed bitcoin core under the main system user “dog” in Linux (Debian). Now I am scratching my head thinking what I should do to change the user to “coindog” which would not be the main system user. I will then run bitcoind service in the background under this new "coindog" user.

Question 1: Can I simply move the .bitcoind folder to another user home folder, change the permissions and be done with it? Does anyone have any manual for it? I googled a lot and currently am in disbelief that no one made this mistake before me? :)

Question 2: "bitcoin core is configured to run under user "bitcoin" (so i read in the standard manuals and the book i have). If i want to set bitcoind to run under username "coindog", is it just an easy change of "user=" and "group=" parameters to the bitcoin.service file?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it’s as easy as moving the .bitcoind directory from one user’s home to another user’s home and then changing ownership of the .bitcoin directory to the new user.